# Python: How to find greater than N rows with non zero cells in greater than M common columns

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have `n x m` matrix and I want to find programatically N or more rows that contains non zero cells in more than M common columns.

For example. Here is the matrix:

```
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

And I looking for 2 or more rows which contains non zero cells in 2 or more common colums. There are several possible results, one of them is:

```
row1: [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
row2: [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
      col1                     col5
```

Is it possible to find all rows combinations, that solve this task?

Comment: Do the rows have to be continuous? What if row4 also had 1's on the same column as row1 and 2.

Comment: Does the input matrix always contain only zeros and ones?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, the matrix contains only 0 and 1

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary If row4 would have 1 in col1 and col5, then it also would be presented in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import combinations

def solve(lst, m):

    col, n = {}, len(lst)
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        col[i] = [j for j, y in enumerate(x) if y]

    for s in xrange(n, m-1, -1):
        for c in combinations(xrange(n), s):
            values  = set(col[c[0]]).intersection(*(col[k] for k in c[1:]))
            if len(values) >= m:
                yield [lst[k] for k in c]

for x in solve(matrix, 2):
    pprint(x)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]]
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations                   
matrix =[[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],   
         [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],   
         [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],   
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],   
         [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],   
         [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],   
         [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]]   

m = 2                                                
n = 6                                                
req_rows = []                                        
ncm = [x for x in combinations(matrix,m)]            
for x in ncm:                                        
    if sum([1 for l in zip(*x) if not 0 in l])>=m:   
        print x
```

**output**

```
([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])
([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])
([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])
([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])
([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
```

Comment: The condition is to find: N or more rows that contains non zero cells in more than **M common columns**. It means that in these M columns all rows should have non zero cells. In your ansver only one column has 3 non zero cells.

Comment: @TuralGurbanov, Ah, my bad.. Will update the answer soon

Comment: great solution! You just made small typo here: `[x for x in combinations(matrix, m)]`. It should be: `[x for x in combinations(matrix, n)]`.

Comment: @TuralGurbanov That is not going to work at all, as there is no combination of size 6 that satisfies such condition. Also this answer will only return combinations of size `m`.